# Stylus pen not firing events for InkCanvas in Windowss 10

Tags: c#, canvas, uwp-xaml, stylus-pen

I have a Dell Latitude 5285 with a paired Dell Active Stylus (PN556W). I was working on a **UWP** test app for trying new things where I happened to notice the Stylus does not kick off any events tied to an InkCanvas.

If I use my finger, the events are triggered.  And I can still write with the stylus on the defined area.  As far as I can find, there are no other types of events associated with InkCanvas for UWP that interact with drawing/stroke/inking/etc.

MainPage.xaml

```
<InkCanvas Name="MyCanvas" Weight="500" Height="500"
    PointerPressed="MyCanvas_PointerPressed"
    PointerMoved="MyCanvas_PointerMoved"
    PointerReleased="MyCanvas_PointerReleased"
    PointerEntered="MyCanvas_PointerEntered"
    PointerExited="MyCanvas_PointerExited">
</InkCanvas>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
InkPresenter myInkPresenter = MyCanvas.InkPresenter;
myInkPresenter.InputDeviceTypes = Windows.UI.Core.CoreInputDeviceTypes.Pen | Windows.UI.Core.CoreInputDeviceTypes.Touch | Windows.UI.Core.CoreInputDeviceTypes.Mouse;
//... Event methods not provided.  Each one essentially adds some text to a textbox for reading output
```

**Has anyone seen this behavior using other paired styli/computers and/or knows how it can it can be corrected?**

*As a side note: I have also tried using the stylus against an app that uses the former Windows 8 Inking/Canvas function, but the pen does not write unless I keep the stylus off and within 3cm of the screen.*

Answer (score 0):

I found the actual event that tracks stroke input lies under the `InkPresenter`, not the `InkCanvas`.

Example:

`MyCanvas.InkPresenter.StrokeInput.StrokeStarted += StrokeInput_StrokeStarted;`

source
[UWP InkPresenter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Input.Inking.InkPresenter)